Unable to Deploy Add-in in Admin Center After Adding SSO Code
I created a Word add-in that requires SSO for necessary permissions. When I tested it in Word online, I successfully added my manifest without errors, and the functions worked correctly.
However, upon uploading my manifest file to the Microsoft 365 Admin Center for centralized deployment of add-ins, I encountered an error: 'There was an error while giving the admin consent. Please try refreshing the add-in from it's details page.' After removing the SSO part from my manifest file, I was able to upload it successfully.
I suspect that I may have misconfigured my Azure AD settings. Could you please assist me in identifying where I went wrong?
I followed this document to set up my Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2
This is my manifest file sso configuration (with my application id): my file sso code in manifest
I have all necessary permission granted:
the permissions that I got
